# What does it do ? (PHP Trait)

Tags: php, traits

I just found this code and I have got no idea how to google it. :-)

***What does the last trait do ?***
I cannot understand it's syntax.
If those lines between the curly braces would be parameters for a new instance, shouldn't it be between parentheses?

```
<?php

namespace Laravel\Dusk;

use Closure;
use BadMethodCallException;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable;
use Facebook\WebDriver\WebDriverDimension;

class Browser
{
    use Concerns\InteractsWithAuthentication,
        Concerns\InteractsWithCookies,
        Concerns\InteractsWithElements,
        Concerns\InteractsWithJavascript,
        Concerns\InteractsWithMouse,
        Concerns\MakesAssertions,
        Concerns\WaitsForElements,
        Macroable {
            __call as macroCall;
        }

    // ...

}
```

The code is from **Laravel\Dusk**.
Here is the original [GitHub repository](https://github.com/laravel/dusk) and [the Class itself](https://github.com/laravel/dusk/blob/1.0/src/Browser.php)

Comment: Try reading this: https://unnikked.ga/understanding-the-laravel-macroable-trait-dab051f09172

Comment: Thx, @PaulCrovella! That is what I wanted to know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
namespace Laravel\Dusk;

use Illuminate\Support\Traits\Macroable;

class Browser
{
    use Macroable {
       __call as macroCall;
    }

    public function __call($method, $parameters)
    {
        // this is defined in THIS class
    }
}
```

Just aliases the `__call` method from `Macroable` trait and makes it available as

```
$this->macroCall($method, $parameters)
```

This is needed to avoid the conflict of the `__call` method which is defined in both this class and the imported trait